# Conexion PDO con MySQL usando MVC

Tags: php, mvc, pdo

quiero solicitar de sus conocimientos y apoyo, estoy intentando realizar la el método para registrar datos en mi base de datos, (Aclaro que el profesor nos enseñó poniendo los metodos en el mismo archivo de la conexion PHP), solo que yo quisiera hacerlo distinto... He creado un archivo en la carpeta modelos que se llama **formularios.modelo.php** donde pretendo crear la clase con todos los metodos para registrar, leer, actualizar y eliminar datos en mi base de datos, posteriormente llamar esos metodos desde **formularios.controlador.php** ubicado en la carpeta controladores, de tal manera que en mi archivo **conexion.php** quede unicamente la clase con mi metodo conexion que conectará a mi base de datos, se que hay una forma de hacerlo usando los metodos como `static public` que se puede llamar sin necesidad de instanciar la clase donde conexión solo usando los doble dos puntos `::`, mi pregunta va de la siguiente manera...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo mi conexión de la siguiente manera, ¿Puedo usar la conexion en un archivo de la misma carpeta? y ¿Como podría realizarlo para entonces en mi archivo **formulario.modelo.php** crear mi metodo para cada una de las acciones con el CRUD?... Muestro mi código que tengo en este momento.

**modelos/Conexion.php**

```
<?php
class Conexion
{
  private $dbHost = "localhost";
  private $dbDatabase = "tiendaweb1";
  private $dbUsuario = "root";
  private $dbPassword = "";

  public function __construc()
  {
  }

  public function conectar()
  {
    try {
      $dbDatos = "mysql:host=" . $this->dbHost . ";dbname=" . $this->dbDatabase;
      $conectando = new PDO($dbDatos, $this->dbUsuario, $this->dbPassword);
      return $conectando;
    } catch (PDOException $error) {
      echo ($error->getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

La conexión se está realizando de manera correcta de esta manera como la tengo actualmente, pero si llamo instancio la clase `Conexion` y el método para conectar en el archivo directamente **formularios.controlador.php**, quiero hacerla en el modelo, actualmente tengo este código.

**formulario.modelo.php**

```
<?php

include_once(__DIR__ . '/../modelos/Conexion.php');

class ModeloFormularios
{
  public function mdlRegistro($tabla, $datos)
  {
    $conecta = new Conexion();
    $stmt = $conecta->conectar();

    
    $stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(typeProduct,img,processor,ram,hardDisk,warranty,cost,description) VALUES(:typeProduct,:img,:processor,:ram,:hardDisk,:warranty,:cost,:description)");
    
    $stmt->bindParam(":typeProduct", $datos["ddlType"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":img", $datos["txtImgRegistro"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":processor", $datos["txtProcesador"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":ram", $datos["ddlRam"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":hardDisk", $datos["ddlDiscoDuro"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":warranty", $datos["ddlGarantia"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":cost", $datos["txtCosto"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":description", $datos["txtDescripcion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  }
}
```

Pero al tenerlo así, me dice un error en mi editor (tengo un plugin que me va indicando los errores mientras escribo código) que dice, "El método prepare no esta definido".

**formularios.controlador.php**

```
<?php

include_once(__DIR__ . '/../modelos/formularios.modelo.php');

if (isset($_POST["btnRegistrar"])) {

  $tabla = "productos";

  $datos = array(
    "typeProduct" => $_POST["ddlType"],
    "img" => $_POST["txtImgRegistro"],
    "processor" => $_POST["txtProcesador"],
    "ram" => $_POST["ddlRam"],
    "hardDisk" => $_POST["ddlDiscoDuro"],
    "warranty" => $_POST["ddlGarantia"],
    "cost" => $_POST["txtCosto"],
    "description" => $_POST["txtDescripcion"],
  );

  $transaccion = new ModeloFormularios();
  $transaccion->mdlRegistro($tabla, $datos);
}
```

Agradezco si me pueden ayudar, sobre como podría organizar el código para realizarlo de tal manera, quiero usar lo del `bindParam` para enviar los datos de manera oculta..

**ACTUALIZADA**
Tomando las respuesta y los comentarios de los colegas que me ayudan con sus comentarios, lo hice de la siguiente manera... Actualizo los fragmentos de código puestos anteriormente.

Debo mostrarles una imagen sobre el error que me muestra el plugin que tengo en mi visual Studio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para que te funcione de ese modo tendrías que retornar desde `conectar()` una instancia de PDO, poniendo algo así: `$pdo=new PDO(...);` y luego, `return $pdo;`Luego en la llamada haces esto: `$conecta = new Conexion(); $pdo=$conecta->conectar();` Ahí **tendrás en `$pdo` una instancia de la conexión**, que podrás usar para las consultas. Si analizas bien el código de la clase `Conexion`, todo se queda en casa, no retornas ni asignas la conexión.

Comment: Excelente comentario @A.Cedano, lo hice asi y el error desaparecio temporalmente, porque al asignar los datos usando `bindParam` me dice que el metodo no está definido.

Comment: ¿Lo que dices ahora es un nuevo error? Pulsa en [edit] y pon ahora cómo tienes el código.

Comment: Esperame actualizo la pregunta con una imagen... Porque ya puse el codigo en el comentario de la respuesta que me dio el otro colega...

Comment: No no imagen no, pon **el texto del código**.

Comment: Perfecto voy...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116020/discussion-between-jonathan-arias-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 2):

**Código antiguo**
para tu caso creo que funcionaría bien lo siguiente lo cual aplicarías a tu caso según lo requieras.

```
<?php
/* Ejecutar una sentencia preparada vinculando varialbes de PHP */
$calorías = 150;
$color = 'red';
$gsent = $gbd->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$gsent->bindParam(':calories', $calorías, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$gsent->bindParam(':colour', $color, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$gsent->execute();
?>
```

**Actualización**
Este proyecto tenía utilizando MVC y PDO con PHP

**Esta es la conexion a la BDD***

```
<?php
    
    class Conexion
    {
        
        //FUNCION PARA CONECTARSE A LA BASE DE DATOS
        public static function conectar()
        {
            
            $link = new PDO('mysql:dbname=titulaciondb;host=localhost', 'root', '123456');
            
            
            //DEFINICION DEL COTEJAMIENTO
            $link->exec('set names utf8');
            $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            
            return $link;
            
        }
        
    }
```

**Estes es un crud básico que lo tenía puedes guiarte para conocer el error**

```
<?php

require_once 'conexion.php';

class ModeloDocente
{

    /*=====================================
        MOSTRAR DOCENTE
        =====================================*/
    public static function mdlMostrarDocente($tabla, $item, $valor)
    {

        if ($item != null) {
            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");

            $stmt->bindParam(':' . $item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt->execute();

            $resultado = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } else {

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");

            $stmt->execute();

            $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

        $stmt = null;
        return $resultado;
    }

    /*=====================================
        CREAR DOCENTE
        =====================================*/
    public static function mdlCrearDocente($tabla, $datos)
    {

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (Nombre_Docente, Apellido_Docente, Genero_Docente, Email_Docente, Cedula_Docente, Password_Docente) VALUES (:nombre, :apellido, :genero, :email, :cedula, :password)");

        $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $datos['nombre'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':apellido', $datos['apellido'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':genero', $datos['genero'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $datos['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':cedula', $datos['cedula'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $datos['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt = null;
    }

    /*=====================================
        ACTUALIZAR DOCENTE
        =====================================*/
    public static function mdlActualizarDocente($tabla, $item1, $valor1, $item2, $valor2)
    {

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET $item1 = :$item1 WHERE $item2 = :$item2");

        $stmt->bindParam(':' . $item1, $valor1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':' . $item2, $valor2, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt = null;
    }

    /*=====================================
        EDITAR DOCENTE
        =====================================*/
    public static function mdlEditarDocente($tabla, $datos)
    {

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET Nombre_Docente = :nombre, Apellido_Docente = :apellido, Genero_Docente = :genero, Email_Docente = :email, Cedula_Docente = :cedula " .
            (isset($datos['password']) ? ",Password_Docente = :password" : "") . " WHERE ID_Docente = :id");

        $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $datos['nombre'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':apellido', $datos['apellido'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':genero', $datos['genero'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $datos['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':cedula', $datos['cedula'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if (isset($datos['password'])) {
            $stmt->bindParam(':password', $datos['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $datos['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt = null;
    }

    /*================================
        ELIMINAR ADMINISTRADOR DEL SISTEMA
        ================================*/
    public static function mdlEliminarDocente($tabla, $datos)
    {

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("DELETE FROM $tabla WHERE ID_Docente = :id");

        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $datos, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->execute();
        $statement = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @DavidPacuar, sin embargo al utilizar el `$stmt->bindParam(":typeProduct", $datos["ddlType"], PDO::PARAM_STR);` en la asignación de todos los datos a los campos, al frente me dice que el metodo ``` bindParam ``` no está definido...  Lo hice Asi. `$conecta = new Conexion();  $stmt = $conecta->conectar(); $stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(typeProduct,img,processor,ram,hardDisk,warranty,cost,description) VALUES(:typeProduct,:img,:processor,:ram,:hardDisk,:warranty,:cost,:description)");`

Comment: Revisa la actualización compa

Comment: Gracias David, sin embargo estas usando en el código la palabra reservada static lo cual permite usar la clase sin necesidad de instanciarla, solamente usando los `::` en mi caso quisiera hacerla instanciando la clase, osea sin usar el `static` no se si sea posible, por eso vine al foro a preguntar... Sino pues me tocaria cambiar mi código y hacerla como tu ejemplo.